# Best way to access current user of web application in class library

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

We are currently working on a project which uses entity framework for data storage. One of the requirements for this project is that we store, Created, CreatedBy, Modified, ModifiedBy etc against each entity.

We have chosen to separate the the data from the web application by using two projects, 1 for data, and one for the web application.

I have created a interface, `IAuditable` which is defined in the Data Project like so:

```
Public Interface IAuditable

    Property Created As DateTime
    Property CreatedBy As ApplicationUser

    Property Modified As DateTime
    Property ModifiedBy As ApplicationUser

    Property IsDeleted As Boolean
    Property Deleted As DateTime
    Property DeletedBy As ApplicationUser

End Interface
```

I was hoping that by doing it like this i would be able to override the `SaveChanges` method of the `DbContext` in the Data Project like so:

```
Public Overrides Function SaveChanges() As Integer

    For Each AuditableEntity In ChangeTracker.Entries(Of IAuditable)

        If AuditableEntity.State = EntityState.Added Or AuditableEntity.State = EntityState.Modified Then

            Dim CurrentUser As ApplicationUser = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity

            AuditableEntity.Entity.Modified = DateTime.Now
            AuditableEntity.Entity.ModifiedBy = CurrentUser

            If AuditableEntity.State = EntityState.Added Then

                AuditableEntity.Entity.Created = DateTime.Now
                AuditableEntity.Entity.CreatedBy = CurrentUser

            Else

                AuditableEntity.Property(Function(p) p.Created).IsModified = False
                AuditableEntity.Property(Function(p) p.CreatedBy).IsModified = False

            End If

        End If

    Next

    Return MyBase.SaveChanges()

End Function
```

Now, the problem is that obviously `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` doesn't exist in the class library.

What is the best way to pass the current user into the this function?

I know i can add `System.Web` to the project and then will be able to access the `HttpContext` however this will limit me to only using the data in a web application... and there is the possibility in the future that we will need to use this data class in other types of project.

Is it a good idea to have a separate `DbContext`, which inherits from the `DbContext` in the Class Library? within the web application that does have access to `HttpContext`?

Comment: Have you checked Thread.CurrentPrincipal to see if it's set correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using an `override` why not declare a new method which takes the user Identity as an argument, as so:

```
public int SaveChanges(Identity identity)
{
    // Your code
    return SaveChanges();
}
```

Of course you will have to modify your `SaveChanges` calls to then pass through the identity:

```
db.SaveChanges(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity);
```